# Append to file only if it exists

Tags: bash

I've seen several answers on SO about how to append to a file if it exists and create a new file if it doesn't (`echo "hello" >> file.txt`) or overwrite a file if it exists and create one if it doesn't (`echo "hello" > file.txt`).

But how do I make sure that `echo "hello"` only works and appends to the file if it already exists and raises an error if it doesn't?

EDIT: Right now, I'm already checking for the file using `[ -f file.txt ]`. I was wondering if there's a way in which I could simply use `echo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the file is either nonexistent or both readable and writable, you can try to open it for reading first to determine whether it exists or not, e.g.:

```
command 3<file 3<&- >>file
```

`3<&-` may be omitted in most cases as it's unexpected for a program to start reading from file descriptor `3` without redirecting it first.

Proof of concept:

```
$ echo hello 3<file 3<&- >>file
bash: file: No such file or directory
$ ls file
ls: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory
$ touch file
$ echo hello 3<file 3<&- >>file
$ cat file
hello
$
```

This works because redirections are processed from left to right, and a redirection error causes the execution of a command to halt. So if `file` doesn't exist (or is not readable), `3<file` fails, the shell prints an error message and stops processing this command. Otherwise, `3<&-` closes the descriptor (`3`) associated with `file` in previous step, `>>file` reopens `file` for appending and redirects standard output to it.

Answer (score 6):

I think a simple `if` as proposed in the other answers would be best. However, here are some more exotic solutions:

#### Using `dd`

`dd` can do the check and redirection in one step

```
echo hello | dd conv=nocreat of=file.txt
```

Note that `dd` prints statistics to stderr. You can silence them by appending `2> /dev/null` but then the warning `file does not exist` goes missing too.

#### Using a custom Function

When you do these kind of redirections very often, then a reusable function would be appropriate. Some examples:

Run `echo` and redirect only if the file exists. Otherwise, raise the syntax error `-bash: $(...): ambiguous redirect`.

```
ifExists() { [ -f "$1" ] && printf %s "$1"; } 
echo hello >> "$(ifExists file.txt)"
```

Always run `echo`, but print a warning and discard the output if the file does not exist.

```
ifExists() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    printf %s "$1"
  else
    echo "File $1 does not exist. Discarding output." >&2
    printf /dev/null
  fi
} 
echo hello >> "$(ifExists file.txt)"
```

Please note that `ifExists` cannot handle all file names. If you deal with very unusual filenames ending with newlines, then the subshell `$( ...)` will remove those trailing newlines and the resulting file will be different from the one specified. To solve this problem you have to use a pipe.

Always run `echo`, but print a warning and discard the output if the file does not exist.

```
appendIfExists() {
  if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    cat >> "$1"
  else
    echo "File $1 does not exist. Discarding output." >&2
    return 1
  fi
} 
echo hello | appendIfExists file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check:

```
if [ -f file.txt ]; then
  echo "hello" >> file.txt
else
  echo "No file.txt" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

There's no way in `bash` to alter how `>>` works; it will always (try to) create a file if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
if [ -f "filename" ]; then
echo "hello" >>filename
fi
```